# Trying to use a macro in C to color text, but get: error: expected ')'

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I'm trying to write a macro based terminal string colorer in C for my future projects. So far all I've got is this:

```
#define ANSI_RED     "\x1b[31m"
#define ANSI_GREEN   "\x1b[32m"
#define ANSI_YELLOW  "\x1b[33m"
#define ANSI_BLUE    "\x1b[34m"
#define ANSI_MAGENTA "\x1b[35m"
#define ANSI_CYAN    "\x1b[36m"
#define ANSI_RESET   "\x1b[0m"

#define ANSI_COLOR(color, string) color string ANSI_RESET

#define FOREGROUND 38
#define BACKGROUND 48

#define RGB_COLOR(plane, r, g, b, string) "\033[" plane ";" r ";" g ";" b "m" string ANSI_RESET
```

The `ANSI_COLOR` macro works just fine, but when I try to use the `RGB_COLOR` one like this:

```
printf( RGB_COLOR(FOREGROUND, 248, 42, 148, "Starting the server:\n") );
```

I get an error:

```
/c-http-server/main.c:17:23: error: expected ')'
    printf( RGB_COLOR(FOREGROUND, 248, 42, 148, "Starting the server:\n") );
                      ^
/c-http-server/libs/c-chalk/chalk.h:11:20: note: expanded from macro 'FOREGROUND'
#define FOREGROUND 38
                   ^
/c-http-server/main.c:17:11: note: to match this '('
    printf( RGB_COLOR(FOREGROUND, 248, 42, 148, "Starting the server:\n") );
```

I've looked for this problem on SO, and most of the solutions were about finding the extra ')', but I can't find one in my code.

I'd be thrilled if anyone could help me find the issue, maybe I'm just blind and missed something obvious.

Comment: One way to debug this is to run only the precompiler and inspect the output.

Comment: You need to specify the colours as strings too: `#define FOREGROUND "38"`. Another way is to use stringification operator in the macro.

Comment: A better way would be not using macros at all but functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to concatenate strings and integers which is not possible.

As a quick fix, you could try

```
#define FOREGROUND "38"
#define BACKGROUND "48"
```

and use it like

```
printf( RGB_COLOR(FOREGROUND, "248", "42", "148", "Starting the server:\n") );
```

On the other hand, it should be possible (and cleaner) to [stringize](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3/cpp/Stringification.html) the parameters (untested):

```
#define xstr(a) str(a)
#define str(a) #a
#define RGB_COLOR(plane, r, g, b, string) "\033[" str(plane) ";" str(r) ";" str(g) ";" str(b) "m" string ANSI_RESET
```

Note the detour via the `xstr`and `str` because stringization prevents macro expansion as @John Bollinger commented correctly.

Comment: Yes and no on the stringification, because the stringification operator suppresses macro expansion of the argument to which it is applied.  There are workarounds, but the specific alternative definition you present for `RGB_COLOR` will not work as the OP wants.